# 'A valid React element (or null) must be returned' error with one of the component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is something like this

```
var data = [
    {id: 1, taskName: "Pete Hunt", standarDescription: "This is one comment", emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo", empRating : "1"},
    {id: 2, taskName: "Pete Hunt", standarDescription: "This is one comment", emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo", empRating : "1"},
    {id: 3, taskName: "Pete Hunt", standarDescription: "This is one comment", emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo", empRating : "1"},
    {id: 4, taskName: "Pete Hunt", standarDescription: "This is one comment", emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo", empRating : "1"},
    {id: 5, taskName: "Pete Hunt", standarDescription: "This is one comment", emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo", empRating : "1"}
];

var Tableforbasictask = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <div className="downloadlinks">
      <table className="table table-bordered table-striped-col nomargin" id="table-data">
      <tbody>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>Task  Name</td>
            <td>Standard Discription of Task</td>
            <td>Employee Comment</td>
            <td>Employee rating</td>
        </tr>
        <TableforbasictaskList data={this.props.data} />
        <TableforbasictaskForm />
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TableforbasictaskForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="commentForm">
          Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

var Addcontenttotable = React.createClass({
render: function() {
  return (
    <tr><td>{this.props.taskName}</td>
        <td>{this.props.standarDescription}</td>
        <td>{this.props.emplComment}</td>
        <td>{this.props.empRating}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
});

var TableforbasictaskList = React.createClass({
render: function() {
  var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
    return (
      <Addcontenttotable taskName={comment.taskName} standarDescription={comment.standarDescription} emplComment={comment.emplComment} empRating={comment.empRating} key={comment.id}>
      </Addcontenttotable>
    );
  });
  return (
      {commentNodes}
  );
}
});
ReactDOM.render(<div><Tableforbasictask data={data}  /></div>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

All I am trying to do is List the detail from the `Json` data into a table form . I will be adding an API to fetch that JSON in Future

but I am getting following error

> Error: TableforbasictaskList.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Here is the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41118/)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to format your code in this question or even in fiddle editor?

Comment: @The Pardon I fixed the Fiddle Link now please have a look

Answer (score 24, accepted):

React component must [have only one root node](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html)., as you are using `TableforbasictaskList` inside `table` you need wrap `commentNodes` in `<tbody>`., also inside `Tableforbasictask` move `TableforbasictaskForm` from `table`

```
var TableforbasictaskList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // .....
    return (<tbody>{commentNodes}</tbody>);
  }
});

var Tableforbasictask = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className="downloadlinks">
      <table
        className="table table-bordered table-striped-col nomargin"
        id="table-data"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr align="center">
            <td>Task  Name</td>
            <td>Standard Discription of Task</td>
            <td>Employee Comment</td>
            <td>Employee rating</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <TableforbasictaskList data={this.props.data} /> 
      </table>
      <TableforbasictaskForm />
    </div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/dzyo847v/)

Comment: thank you I understood, Thank you I am a PHP devloper so working around in ReactJs is bit PAA ;) , But I am sure I will get a hang of it

Answer (score 15):

`render` should return single root element https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41120/

```
return (<div>
    {commentNodes}
</div>);
```

Update. More valid option using tbody as a wrapper

```
return (<tbody>
    {commentNodes}
</tbody>);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41125/

Comment: @YuryTarbanko     But its not mapping the value properly into the right Column , Can you instruct me how I can do that ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You already have divs inside tables which is not ok. :) You could use `tr` or `td` depending on how you need to arrange elements. Or even better you could use divs instead and use styles to make a layout.